# How to export conda environment while including packages installed within R terminal?

Tags: r, package, export, installation, conda

I have a few R packages that won't work when installed with conda so I must install them directly in R.

Here is how I exported my environment:

```
conda env export --name python3 --file ./py3_env.yml
```

Here is my exported environment:

```
https://pastebin.com/XWdeYZc4
```

Packages I've installed like `WGCNA` and `edgeR` which are crucial for my environment do not appear.

```
(python3) Joshs-MacBook-Pro:~ mu$ ls ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/R/library/WGCNA/
CITATION    INDEX       NAMESPACE   data        html
DESCRIPTION Meta        R       help        libs
```

**I want to export my environment so I can have others install it on different machines.  How can I do this and also capture the packages installed via R?**

Comment: `library()` will give all installed packages. `sessionInfo()` will give the packages loaded into the current session.

Comment: Please include the exported environment directly into the post, or don't include it if its not necessary. Why put a URL in code formatting?

Comment: I'm linking the conda export externally because it is verbose for a SO post and also to verify that the R packages I have installed via the R console were not considered during the conda environment export lord tenebrous.

Comment: Could you confirm why you didn't install WGCNA and edgeR from bioconda? Crossing the streams by using both install.packages and conda is pretty dangerous. There are some R-based tools like `packrat` that help fix your package requirements; but it's way easier to use conda for everything

Comment: When I install wgcna through conda it breaks my R with trap errors.  I can get the exact error later .

Comment: I think it still has lots of challenge to use conda for R package/environment managment. I am wondering whether this question has been successfully solved? Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get around this by ONLY INSTALLING PACKAGES THROUGH CONDA..especially for R.  Good luck, with a lot of R packages there are 5000 dependencies that each have their own dependencies and none of them are lightweight. With a few exceptions, `vegan` being one of them.